# "show.std" function removes p value formatting in tab_plot (sjPlot)

Tags: linear-regression, sjplot

I have a simple linear model like the one here:

step1 <- lm(data= iris, Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width)

I can make a table expressing it using sjPlot:

```
tab_model(step1)
```

[image]

But adding standardised beta values changes the formatting of the p values:

```
tab_model(step1,
          show.std = T)
```

[image]

Is there a way to stop this from happening?

Comment: This was a bug in sjPlot, should be fixed now (on GitHub, you can try to install the package from here: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daniel provided the solution.
It was a bug in sjPlot.

Using devtools to install sjPlot worked:

```
install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot")
```

I had a problem with permissions so I also had to change the install location:

```
with_libpaths(new = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/library", install_github("strengejacke/sjPlot"))
```

and then changed the default library:

```
 .libPaths("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/library")
```